# Adding a processor after unmarshaling in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, gson, marshalling

I have a camel routes setup shown below.
In `stage` folder i can see message getting marshal properly into a json.
but while un-marshaling on this line  `body.setA("modified A");`
i get a null pointer exception basically body is null.. **Why** ?

```
from("direct:stage").marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
.to("file://stage");

from("file://stage").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
.process(new Processor() {                  
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        MyTest body = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyTest.class);           
        body.setA("modified A");
    }
}).to("direct:b");
```

Comment: Comment out the second "from" code and see if what is getting saved to the stage folder. If nothing is being saved or file is empty then that is why body does not exist and you get nullpointerexception.

Comment: discussion from mailing list : http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/why-adding-a-processor-after-unmarshaling-in-apache-camel-throw-nullpointer-td5772513.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason your body is most likely null is due to the configuration of the unmarshal call.  In order to un-marshal a json object you need to provide the class the string needs to be un-marshaled to.  I am not sure 100% how to do it in DSL, but I have done this previously like follows:

```
//In my spring context

<dataFormats>
    <json id="jack" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.fun.model.TestModel"/>
</dataFormats>

//in my routeBuilder
from("")
    .unmarshal("jack")
    .to("other stuff");
```